# Accessing a user's Claim Store from another application

Tags: 2013-sp1, smarttarget, ambient-data-framework

I am wondering whether it's possible to have access to a user's claim store from another application.

Take the following scenario for example:

- There is a website which has ADF installed. The claim store is getting populated by the default and custom cartridges while the user browses around
- The website is coupled with another web app (a rest service) which handles SmartTarget querying instead of the website itself.
- Is it possible to have access to the original user's claim store (populated on the website's end) from within the custom web service in order to perform SmartTarget querying with the relevant user data/triggers? My understanding is that each CD application has it's own ADF context. Am I wrong? Do note that this is Tridion 2013SP1 coupled with SmartTarget 2014SP1

I have found the "Claim forwarding mechanism" in the online docs, but this doesn't quite look like what I am looking for.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not pass the claims as parameters to the call to the other service (which is pretty much what smarttarget does)? As long as you're calling the service from within the same web app context/session, you have access to that user's claimstore.

Comment: Yeah, sounds reasonable, sometimes we tend to over-complicate simple things :). Care to make it an answer so I may accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably look into passing any relevant claims that are currently in the claimstore as parameters to this external service - which is very similar to what SmartTarget is doing.

Basically, grab the values you need - or perhaps the whole claimstore? - and pass it on to the personalization service running outside your web application. Since your calling client code runs within the webapp, you have full access to the claimstore and won't have to do any special/complicated code to share the context.

Comment: Indeed!,  in-case if you are sending the claim values like logged in user info, any other confidential claims, ensure that they are not passed as plain text values between the web applications